# In webapp billing for itunes ios stuff

Tags: iphone, ios, paypal, itunes

I have wrappers for Android/iOS webviews that basically just point to the mobile website which is a web app done in html5.

Content is sold on the mobile site. I have payment options in place for google wallet and paypal now.

Can I still put this in the Apple app store or is it going to violate their terms?  I'm thinking for the iOS app I can put a cookie in that says its an Apple device and then hide the other payment options easily, but how do I then integrate iTunes in-app billing for the content?

Comment: Apple will reject the app if all it does is show a web view to a website. What's the point of an app if all the user needs is a bookmark in Safari?

Comment: It's pretty common look into phonegap bro